# Partition ${1, 2,.. 2012}$ into $671$ subsets so that all the subsets have the same sum.

Tags: number-theory

Partition ${1, 2,.. 2012}$ into $671$ subsets so that all the subsets have the same sum.
Prove that there exists such a partition.

Is there any good starting point for this type of question? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by finding what the sum of each subset has to be.  If the sum of all the numbers is not a multiple of $671$ you are sunk, but the questioner has promised you a solution.  Each subset needs to sum to $\frac {2012\cdot 2103}{2 \cdot 671}=3018$, which is notable for being $\frac 32 \cdot 2012$.  I would start by pulling out subsets $\{2012,1006\},\{2011,1007\},\ldots \{1510,1508\}$ (how many is that?) then work on showing that with all the little numbers left, there is plenty of freedom to get there.